# How to delay key up event in angular?

Tags: angular, dom-events

I want to delay the key up event in angular 4. Just want to wait 500ms to fire key up event. Trying to follow the example in [angular.io tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6#herosearchcomponent)
it appears that `updateText()` is not invoked from observable. Look like issue with observable.

```
   @Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Key event Demo {{name}}</h2>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h4> KeyUp Event: </h4> 
      <input #keyUpInput (keyup)="onKeyUp(keyUpInput.value)">
      <div>
       <h5> KeyUp Text: </h5>
        <p>{{values}}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h4> KeyUp Event With Delay: </h4> 
      <input #keyUpInputDelay (keyup)="onKeyUpDelay(keyUpInputDelay.value)">
      <div>
       <h5> KeyUp Text: </h5>
        valuesDelay: <p>{{valuesDelay}}</p>
        valuesDelayText:  <p>{{valuesDelayText}}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App implements OnInit  {
  public name:string;
  public values:string = '';
  public valuesDelay:string = '';
  public valuesDelayText:string = '';

  private typeTerm = new Subject<string>();

  constructor() {
    this.name = `Angular! v${VERSION.full}`
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.typeTerm.debounceTime(300).distinctUntilChanged().map(term => this.updateText(term));
  }

  public onKeyUp(value: string): void { 
    this.values += value + ' | ';
  }

  public onKeyUpDelay(value: string): void { 
    this.valuesDelay += value + ' | ';
    this.typeTerm.next(value);
  }

  public updateText(value: string): void { 
    this.valuesDelayText += value + ' | ';
  }
}
```

[Sample plnkr Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/9dDYQf1DYtrQl6MrIxtF?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved:**

Just need to subscribe to observable

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.typeTerm.debounceTime(5000).distinctUntilChanged().subscribe(term => this.updateText(term));
  }
```